# Reference and datatype checking, are these the same?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function in my library that checks the validity of an object reference (object here meaning, a reference to a created HTML element, mostly DIV's). It looks like this:

```
function varIsValidRef(aRef) {
    return ( !(aRef == null || aRef == undefined) && typeof(aRef) == "object");
}
```

While experimenting i found that this has the same effect:

```
function varIsValidRef(aRef) {
    return (aRef) && typeof(aRef) == "object";
}
```

I understand there are some controversies regarding the short hand () test? While testing against various datatypes (null, undefined, integer, float, string, array) i could find no difference in the final outcome. The function seem to work as expected.

Is it safe to say that these two versions does the exact same thing?

Comment: +1. Thought I could answer this. Just confused myself instead.

Comment: It get's even more interesting with:  return (aRef) && typeof(aRef) == "object" && (typeof(aRef.length)=="undefined") ? true:false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in my opinion these functions don't work the same:

**First option**
If `aRef` is not `undefined` or `null` and the type of the var is `object` it returns true.

**Second option**
First we convert `aRef` to a boolean. Values like `null`, `undefined` and `0` become `false`, everything else become `true`. If it is `true` (so not one of those values) it checks if the type is object.

So the second option return false if `aRef` is `0`, something you don't want. And it isn't option a elegant way to check it, because you check if an object or string or something is equal to a boolean.

And at least they don't return the same thing. The first option returns a boolean, but the second option returns the value you put in the function if `(aRef)` is false:

```
varIsValidRef(0);
>>> 0

varIsValidRef('');
>>> ""

varIsValidRef(undefined);
>>> undefined

varIsValidref(null);
>>> null
```

Because JavaScript use these values as falsy values you don't see the difference between these return values if you use if statements or something like that.

So I suggest you to use the first option.

Comment: I also have a third version where i try to exclude arrays turning up as valid objects (although that might be covered by the () test?):

return (aRef) && typeof(aRef) == "object" && (typeof(aRef.length)=="undefined") ? true:false;

Answer (score 1):

they are strongly different:

```
!(aRef == null || aRef == undefined)
```

this part is evaluated to *false* with any of these `"null", null, "undefined", undefined`

```
(aRef)
```

while this other with any of these `0, "", false, null, undefined, NaN`

Answer (score 0):

They don't do the same, though they end up with the same results.

The first function is more strict in what it will count as false together, or if it's not, if its an object.

The second function will check if `aRef` is `!false` or not any of the falsy values (ie `[]`, `null`, `undefined`) and check if the type is an object if it isn't.

I would prefer the first function, since its stricter in what it accepts, but if its all the same the function which performs the best should be used.

As for the controversy, its true that you have to be careful about how/when you use falsy values in equations but if it does what you want it to do (and for that you'll need to know what falsy values are) and you implement it correctly it should be no problem. The two are hard to put together though. So with that, if this does what you want it to do, and nothing more or less, by all means use it.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting case, but it seems logical for both to behave the same way despite being ***totally different***. Lets see the first staement.

```
return ( !(aRef == null || aRef == undefined) && typeof(aRef) == "object");
```

Here,

`null` and `undefined` both denote a `false` state combined with the `!` infront, makes it equal to the expression `aRef` which will return `true` in case both are either not *null* or not *undefined*.